# Why merging requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar() objects doesn't work at all?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I have this dict:

```
cloudflare_cookies = {'__cfduid': 'd46ed690cd9088175f95adcbc6775ee351519082779', 'cf_clearance': '6f72b46f12e0f5491e84abc94772c48149b768ef-1519082786-86400'}
```

Then, I want to create one single **requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()** object from the two cookies that are in that dict variable like:

```
    cookie1 = {
                  name: '__cfduid'
                  value: 'd46ed690cd9088175f95adcbc6775ee351519082779'
               }

    cookie2 = {
                  name: 'cf_clearance'
                  value: '6f72b46f12e0f5491e84abc94772c48149b768ef-1519082786-86400'
              }

   cookie_final = cookie1 + cookie2
```

My code is the followig:

```
    cookie1 = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
    cookie2 = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
    cookie1.set("name", "__cfduid")
    cookie1.set("value", cloudflare_cookies['__cfduid'])
    cookie2.set("name", "cf_clearance")
    cookie2.set("value", cloudflare_cookies['cf_clearance'])
    cookie_final = requests.cookies.merge_cookies(cookie1,cookie2)
    print (cloudflare_cookies)
    print (cookie_final)
```

But what I get printed is:

```
{'__cfduid': 'd46ed690cd9088175f95adcbc6775ee351519082779', 'cf_clearance': '6f72b46f12e0f5491e84abc94772c48149b768ef-1519082786-86400'}
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie name=cf_clearance for />, <Cookie value=6f72b46f12e0f5491e84abc94772c48149b768ef-1519082786-86400 for />]>
```

Only **cookie2** is inside **cookie_final** at the end.
I already tried cookie1.update(cookie2) and again, cookie2 takes place of cookie1 in the end.

What could be going wrong???

Comment: like this answer from naren:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692514/python3-requests-how-to-merge-cookiejars?rq=1

Comment: None?? knows?! damn it I'am almost 3 hours on this!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
import requests

cloudflare_cookies = {'__cfduid': 'd46ed690cd9088175f95adcbc6775ee351519082779', 'cf_clearance': '6f72b46f12e0f5491e84abc94772c48149b768ef-1519082786-86400'}

cookie_final = requests.cookies.merge_cookies(requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar(), cloudflare_cookies)

print(cookie_final)
```

Does what you want, cookies.merge_cookies can merge a cookiejar with a dict

Comment: Thank you so much my friend!

Comment: Please accept my question if it answered your problem.

Comment: Course, sorry I just forgot